# stringstream removes leading 0s

Tags: c++, stringstream

In the following code:

```
stringstream ss;
int a = 0;
ss << str;
ss >> a;
cout << a;
```

If `str = "05"`, `stringstream` removes the leading 0, and prints 5.
How can be this avoided?

Comment: By making `a` a `std::string`, which might, depending on the acceptable input, reduce your code to `std::cout << str;`. `int` does not hold any information about the format it was extracted from. You need to make your own parser if you want that.

Comment: How would an `int` have a _leading_ zero? It doesn't make sense until you go to print it. [How can I pad an int with leading zeros when using cout << operator?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1714515)

Comment: That's a *leading `0`* not *trailing*. As far as numbers go `05` and `5` are the same thing. The number doesn't care what textual representation you converted it from.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp. The link answers mine one too!

Answer (score 4):

You are converting a string to an int. an int doesn't have any concept of leading zeros, it's just a number. If you want to print leading zeros in a stream, you might be interested in the [setfill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) and [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) manipulators. The following code will print a leading 0 if `a` is only one digit long.

```
cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << a;
```

Comment: Typo, `ss` should be `cout`, and there is a `>>` that should be `<<`.